# Reconfigure Routing and Remote Access Service Windows server 2012

Tags: remote-access

I have configured Routing and Remote Access Service for VPN, is there a way to reconfigure it again with the wizard?
If I delete the server and add it again it says that it's already configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, in almost the way you are currently doing it

Rather then click delete (which just removes it from the mmc window) click on disable routing and remote access. This will of course stop anyone connecting until you have finished the wizard again. To run the wizard click on Configure and Enable routing and Remote Access which will be available again

[image]